# In Symfony, how to call controller function in Menubuilder?

Tags: php, symfony

I have written one function as getAccess() in controller file `Appbundle/Controller/BackendController.php`.

I want to access this controller's method in `Menu/Menubuilder.php` file. How can I do that?

Menu and Appbundle folders are at same level.

Comment: You should extract this function getAccess() into separate service and pass it by dependency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, a controller can not be called in menuBuilder and it would not be "clean". I suggest you create a manager or service that contains this feature and call your service in your controller and in MenuBuilder.

```
namespace App\Service;

class MessageGenerator
{
    public function getHappyMessage()
    {
        $messages = [
            'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
            'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
            'Great work! Keep going!',
        ];

        $index = array_rand($messages);

        return $messages[$index];
    }
}
```

What version of symfony are you on?

Comment: Symfony version is 3.4

Comment: While the suggestion of extracting getAccess to it's own service is good, the posted code does not seem relevant.

Comment: This is an example I will put in response what he could have on his side however can we see the code of getAccess ()?

Comment: @Heyden7611, Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies.

So, you can create your function getAccess() in trait file and just use it in  BackendController.php and  Menubuilder.php

```
trait ezcReflectionReturnInfo {
    function getReturnType() { /*1*/ }
    function getReturnDescription() { /*2*/ }
}

class ezcReflectionMethod extends ReflectionMethod {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}

class ezcReflectionFunction extends ReflectionFunction {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created service as follows:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;


class UserAccessService {

    private $conn;
    private $container;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ContainerInterface $container, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
        $this->conn = $entityManager;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
```

and added following code in services.yml:

```
app.service.useraccessservice:
        class: AppBundle\Services\UserAccessService
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager','@service_container','@security.token_storage']

    app.menu_builder:
        class: AppBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory", "@security.authorization_checker", '@security.token_storage', '@translator', '@app.service.useraccessservice','@kernel']
        public: true
        tags:
            - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createMainMenu, alias: main_menu }
            - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createManagementMenu, alias: management_menu }
            - { name: knp_menu.menu_builder, method: createUserMenu, alias: user_menu }
```

It works as expected.